# Firebase sign-in with-google reloads vue spa

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I'm working on a SPA with Vue3 and Firebase.

I use Firebase with sign-in-with-google, and it works properly for login as it keeps the user logged in after authentication.

But, if I try to do something right after the google authentication, it reloads the page, and therefore my script stops before executing the new user creation part.

```
        const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
    return await getRedirectResult(auth)
        .then((result) => {
            // TODO: I want to do stuff here with result.user
            // but it reloads the page before reaches this part
        }).catch((error) => {
        });
```

It would be to best, to return the user from this function, as I call it in vuex store, where I could do my necessary changes.
The actual change I want to do is to create new user data and load it to the server.
I could do it with a cloud function, but I do not want to pay for it.